# Is there a scanr counterpart in java?

Tags: java

Haskell has this `scanr` function with signature `(a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> [b]` which is a variant of fold/reduce, but produces all the intermediate values out. Is there a java counterpart either in standard library or in guava?

Comment: What do you mean by "produces all the intermediate values out"?

Comment: Suppose if you want cumulative sum you could do `scanr (+) 0 [1,2,3]` will give you `[6,5,3]`. and `scanl 0 (+) [1,2,3]` would be `[1,3,6]` (Which is more natural I suppose)

Comment: You can do something similar using a `Stream` and a custom `Collector`. I'll leave that as an exercise ;-)

Comment: I'm not aware of any library implementing this. `scanl` is pretty trivial to implement, for `scanr` you'd have to jump through an additional hoop.